# Intellisense for modules in VS Code for require statement

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Good day!
I'm trying to use intellisense in the VS Code for modules exported using relative pathes.

In the VS Code I've installed plugin "path-intellisense".
In the settings.json:

```
"path-intellisense.mappings": {
    "/": "${workspaceRoot}/srv/",
    "modules": "${workspaceRoot}/srv/modules"
}
```

But when I'm trying to include module via require statement the VS Code doesn't highlight imported module and doesn't extract properties/methods:

```
let cRequest = require("modules/google/authClient");
```

Auto-complete for path is working, but variable "cRequest" is not an object of imported module.

Its works ok if set path to module like:

```
let cRequest = require("../modules/google/authClient");
```

What is the possible way to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you add a `/` before your `modules` like this => `let cRequest = require("/modules/google/authClient");` ?

Comment: Nothing happened. Moreover, path intellisense doesn't work in this case.